Databricks Spark throwing [GC (Allocation Failure) ] message
I used this code to update a new_df. Idea is to get all the records between date_updated and stop time and assign them a number which i will used in group by in next steps. so basically assigning same number to every group between dateupdated and stop time.
# Create an empty DataFrame
new_df = spark.createDataFrame([], df_filtered.schema)
i = 0

# Collect rows of df_filtered_sku1 as a list
rows = df_filtered_sku1.collect()
print('Length rows')
print(len(rows)) #781

for row in rows:
    sku = row['Sku']
    start_time = row['DATEUPDATED']
    end_time = row['stop']
    print(sku, start_time, end_time)

    df_temp = df_filtered.filter((df_filtered.DATEUPDATED >= start_time) & (df_filtered.DATEUPDATED <= end_time) & (df_filtered.SKU == sku))
    
    df_temp = df_temp.withColumn("counter", lit(i))
    print('Temp')
    #print(df_temp.count())
    
    # Append the temporary DataFrame to the new_df DataFrame
    print('new Frame')
    new_df = new_df.union(df_temp)
    #print(new_df.count())
    
    i += 1
    if i > 780: print(new_df.count()) #2531
display(new_df)

Rows in df_filtered_sku1 are 781 and final new_df has count of 2531. But when i try to display/show the new_df dataframe it never ends and i checked driver logs it is stuck at Allocation Faliure 
Cluster Specifications:


is the understanding correct ? you have a superset df - df_filtered - then you have a subset df - df_filtered_sku1 - you collect it as a list, loop through the list - filter from superset for each sku, (+ timestamp condition) - assign a number to recs of each sku - append to a df - increment number ? maybe you can ask this as a question with expected results - I am sure you will get better solutions - for eg. maybe create view/tbl on top of df - join + filter then assign dense rank on output for each sku ?

Not an answer to your actual issue but those messages alone aren't an indication of a problem, they'll occur regardless of what you do.
Your likely issue is using collect (which brings all the rows to the server, I assume you are doing this as you want to loop the rows) and then withColumn in a loop for all of your rows from that collect, it's about as bad as you can get from a query plan perspective.  Instead of doing display try to do an explain(true) and see the level of nesting you are asking spark to work through.
I'm not actually sure what that code is meant to do so I can't recommend a workaround to achieve the aim, but as it stands that code will not perform even if it does finish.  To verify that try reducing the number of rows to 1, run then add rows to see the effect.

yes reducing the number of rows to one does work.
